# Powershell Get IIS6 SMTP server domain Alias'

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, iis-6

I'm attempting to write a script that will provide me with some information about the Windows SMTP service. if I use

```
$smtpserver=[adsi]"IIS://localhost/SMTPSVC/1"
```

I can get a whole bunch of properties however I'm not able to get a list of domain alias'.  How would I go about this?

Comment: If there is no direct API for this, try to figure out where the SMTP service stores its configuration, in xml files or more likely in the registry, then access the same stuff with PowerShell.

Comment: Any idea where it's stored?  I checked the registry and the metabase.xml file but no joy